# Why I am getting BOOST_PARAMETER_MAX_ARITY redefined warning while compiling?

Tags: cgal

When I am trying to compile my cgal program I get warning `include/CGAL/config.h:119: warning: "BOOST_PARAMETER_MAX_ARITY" redefined
 #define BOOST_PARAMETER_MAX_ARITY 12`

Is is because how I include the cgal header before boost?

What I have seen so far is,
I can see `include/CGAL/config.h` file defines `BOOST_PARAMETER_MAX_ARITY`
as `#define BOOST_PARAMETER_MAX_ARITY 12` boost also has its own config.h which also defines `BOOST_PARAMETER_MAX_ARITY` as 8.

I am using CGAL-4.13  and boost-1.68.0

Answer (score 0):

CGAL 3D mesher is using boost parameters and this library requires the definition of a macro for the maximum number of arguments. In CGAL, we need at least 12 as you saw. If you have this error message, it means that boost parameters have been included before including the CGAL header `config.h`. One solution is to either define yourself the macro to 12 in you compilation unit before including boost (or the other header including it) or to include the CGAL config file first.

Comment: I tried changing my cmake from `target_link_libraries (${myLib}  Eigen3::Eigen ${Boost_LIBRARIES} CGAL::CGAL
  )`  to `target_link_libraries (${myLib}  Eigen3::Eigen CGAL::CGAL ${Boost_LIBRARIES} 
  )`  but I still have the same problem.

Comment: What I suggested is for example to add `#define BOOST_PARAMETER_MAX_ARITY 12` before including any boost header. I don't understand why you talk about the build system.